# Google Maps SDK for iOS localization

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I have an app that supports only german & english languages and I need to force a map (or even more - geocoder) to be in one of those languages.

While using REST API we can easily set language so all responses, error messages etc are returned properly translated, but I'm worried that REST limits (2500 requests per IP) will not be enough.

Does anyone know if we can set specific language for Google Maps iOS SDK?

Comment: Have you found a workaround or solution since? Because I am also looking for a way of doing that.

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps iOS SDK uses the system region/language settings but doesn't expose any way to manually force any particular language. Geocoding responses (using the SDK classes) and the map labels both reflect these device settings, thankfully.

(Current as of 1.9.2, released February 2015.)

Comment: That is what I thought. Could you please confirm me that it still effective for the last release of Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Comment: Nothing appears to have changed and this is still the behavior I see. Check out their changelog: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases

Comment: That is what I checked after having asked you this question this afternoon. Roger that, thank you for your help and answer.

Comment: In my case it is not using the system language. It's always in English. Any ideas why that could be? Restarting the phone did not help either. The language of the phone in my case is set to Turkish for test purposes.