# iOS : How to load Hebrew map?

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, apple-maps

I am working on an app where i need to load hebrew map and also update map as location change and draw path from initial location to change location.

[image]

I have worked on apple map and google map. But i find some difficulty in loading israel country map on it. Is it possible to load such map on iOS? Any suggestions are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

***To load hebrew map***

Based from this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596087/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-localization), Google Maps iOS SDK uses the system region/language settings but doesn't expose any way to manually force any particular language. Geocoding responses (using the SDK classes) and the map labels both reflect these device settings, thankfully.

***Draw path from initial location to change location***

You can use [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#polylines) to draw lines on the map. A [`GMSPolyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_polyline) object represents an ordered sequence of locations, displayed as a series of line segments. You can set the color of a polyline with `GMSStrokeStyle`.

> To create a polyline, you'll need to specify its path by creating a corresponding `GMSMutablePath` object with two or more points. Each `CLLocationCoordinate2D` represents a point on the Earth's surface. Line segments are drawn between points according to the order in which you add them to the path. You can add points to the path with the `addCoordinate:` or `addLatitude:longitude:` methods.

Example:

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.85, 151.20)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.70, 151.40)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.73, 151.41)];
GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
```

You can check this related [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios).

***Loading israel country map***

Check these links:

- [How to get country specific result with Google autocomplete place api ios sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678607/how-to-get-country-specific-result-with-google-autocomplete-place-api-ios-sdk)
- [Is there a way to display a single country in Google map? It should be only one country, not parts from other countries included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221584/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-single-country-in-google-map-it-should-be-only-one)

Hope this helps!