# How to get address in English language only using GMSGeocoder

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am using GMSGeocoder in my iOS app. And also I am using multiple languages(say English, Arabic).
While using Arabic language I am getting an address in Arabic language. But I want to get the address in English language only.

For this I used `geocoder.accessibilityLanguage = "en-US"`. 
but it didn't work. Could you help me regarding this issue

```
func getAddressForLocation() {
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    geocoder.accessibilityLanguage = "en-US"
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(self.PickupLat),Double(self.PickupLong))
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response , error in
        if let address = response?.firstResult() {
            print(address)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posible duplicated of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596087/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-localization

Comment: It seems that is always going to reflect the language setting of the device.

Comment: @betofarina, then how to get the address only in english language ?

Comment: try to find a way to change the language in the device you are using to english and then go to your app and see if the problem is fixed

Comment: @betofarina...My device language is in english only

Comment: Did you find any solution?