# How to get subLocality and Locality always in English, GMSGeocoder()

Tags: swift, google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-sdk-ios

My situation is same as in this question [How to get address in English language only using GMSGeocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656656/how-to-get-address-in-english-language-only-using-gmsgeocoder)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

My code is

```
  let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
  geocoder.accessibilityLanguage = "en"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a similar **Feature Request** has already been filed in our Public Issue Tracker. Would you mind checking and star it if it's applicable on your use case?

Here is the feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/35828434

Hope this information find you helpful!